# Postgres: Extracting specific words from free text column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table below

```
| id |          description           |
+----+--------------------------------+
| 1  | Added: Apple, Grape and Orange |
| 2  | Orange                         |
| 3  | Removed: Plum and Grape        |
```

Then, I have another table that contains the list of fruits

```
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | apple  |
| 2  | orange |
| 3  | plum   |
```

With these two tables, is it possible to extract every word from the first table on description column that matches all the fruit names?

I want the output like this

```
| id |          description           |  word  |
+----+--------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Added: Apple, Grape and Orange | Apple  |
| 1  | Added: Apple, Grape and Orange | Orange |
| 2  | Orange                         | Orange |
| 3  | Removed: Plum and Grape        | Plum   |
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a simple inner join with pattern matching as join condition:

```
SELECT mytable.id,
       mytable.description,
       fruit.name AS word
FROM mytable
   JOIN fruit ON mytable.description ILIKE '%' || fruit.name || '%';
```

If both tables are large, that will be pretty slow, since it requires a nested loop join. You could use a trigram index on `mytable(description)` to speed up the query.